# writing finb by query with one AND and OR

Tags: spring-data-jpa

How can I write  spring data JPA  exist finBy methods for

```
WHERE Id="1" AND (STATUS ="N" OR STATUS ="K")
```

I had tried findByIdAndStatusOrStatus(1,"N","K") which is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id then you have a unique entity no need to search for it, but i suppose you just gave an unfortunate example. 
Try using the following it will work:

```
findBySomePropertyAndStatusIn(SomeProperty property,Collection<Status> statuses);
```